# Unity Inject parameter in constructor of property being resolved

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I can't find a way to inject parameters in this scenario:

```
class Top
{
    private ISome some;
    public Top()
    {
        some = CreateSome(localRuntimeVariable);
    }

    //I need to pass "some" instance as a InjectionParameter to Child constructor
    [Dependency]
    public Child Child {get;set;}
}
class Child
{
    //I need to inject ISome but it can only be constructed in Top
    public Child(ISome some, Foo foo)
    {
    }
}
public class Usage
{
    private void Top GetTop(Foo foo)
    {
        return unity.Resolve<Top>(new DependencyOverride<Foo>(foo));
        //I expect: Top.Constuctor called and 'some' is assigned;
        //          Top.Child property beeing resolved: Child.Constructor called
        //          'foo' instance to be taken from unity.Resolve<Top>(new DependencyOverride<Foo>(foo));
        //          'some' instance to be taken from Top.some, but how to tell unity to inject it?
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the resolve statement? What references are known when Resolve is invoked?

Comment: Yes, I saw this line. But in which context is this line invoked? Please put the whole method. What references are available when resolve is invoked?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your classes are doing, `Top` creating its own `ISome` instance might be a violation of the Single Responsibility Principal. I feel like ISome should be injected into Top as well. Perhaps you can use a factory and the `InjectionFactory` class in Unity to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Top
{
    public Top( Foo foo, IUnityContainer container )
    {
        some = CreateSome(localRuntimeVariable);
        Child = container.Resolve<Child>(new ParameterOverride("some" some),
            new ParameterOverride("Foo", foo));
    }

    public Child Child {get;private set;}
}

class Child
{
    public Child(ISome some, Foo foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Now you can resolve an instance of top using `unity.Resolve<Top>(new ParameterOverride("Foo", foo))`

The class `Usage` isn't needed. `GetTop(Foo foo)` is just syntactic sugar for `unity.Resolve<Top>(new DependencyOverride<Foo>(foo))`

Comment: well I did exectly as you wrote, but this violates the design principle of our application: DI container should only be used at composition root (app entry point), and having DI container as parameter in constuctor is considered a code smell in our team.

Comment: They don't. I wouldn't ask a question here of someone of my team knew how to solve this.

Comment: Sorry, that was sarcastic question. I would ask your team. If they forbid using a possible solution they have to have a way to solve the problem or they have to review their forbidance. Besides that it can be that your code needs a refactoring. You don't provide that much details than I can form an opinion of that, but your design feels a bit uncommon.

Comment: Well, then I way conclude that, you can't pass parameters to properties mark as dependencies, from the class they are declared in. And I need to redesign my code.